# Changes in Orbix Idl compiler flags from 3.3 to 6.3

Tags: corba, idl, compiler-flags

I am quite new to the IDL compiler and am trying to port a decade old code from 3.3 to 6.3 (C++) and I see that the old compiler flags like -A -B -N are no longer valid in the new compiler. Can some one point me to a link which lists or maps the flags.

Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Instead of porting to Orbix 6.3, why not port to a full open source CORBA implementation like TAO, JacORB, R2CORBA?

Comment: I am not the decision maker, but can recommend if I am not able to get the info I need.

Answer (score 0):

See page 799 of [the PDF documentation](http://documentation.progress.com/output/Iona/orbix/6.3.5/CORBA%20Programmers%20Guide,%20C++.pdf).

Note that Orbix was recently acquired by [MicroFocus](http://www.microfocus.com/), so you could ping them for support.